# Como puedo obtener los valores CYMK de un input color

Tags: javascript, css, html5, color

estoy tratando de obtener los valores CYAN YELLOW MAGENTA Y BLACK de un input color HTML, los valores mencionados van de 0 a 100 por cada uno para obtener un color, he visto que ya hay sitios que realizan esto pero existe alguna forma de hacerlo mas facil?

Por ejemplo, desde un input color ingresado, como puedo obtener solo el valor CYAN de un color y plasmarlo con un document.getElementById() en un parrafo mas abajo. Alguien me puede guiar? quedo atento gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función que te permita convertir colores hexadecimales a CMYK, una vez los tengas te será más facil usarlos como quieras, aquí te dejo un ejemplo con paso a paso que toma el color del input, lo convierte y luego muestra el resultado en consola:

```js
(() => {
  // función util para determinar si un string es un color hexadecimal
  function isHex(hex) {
    return /^#[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$/g.test(hex);
  }

  // función para convertir un color hex a cmyk
  function hexToCmyk(hex) {
    // 1. valida si el color es un color hexadecimal válido
    if (!isHex(hex)) throw `invalid hex "${hex}"`;

    // 2. separa el hex en parejas: #32A852 = 32 A8 52
    const pairs = hex.match(/[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}/g);

    // 3. convierte a RGB (o valores decimales) y divide
    // cada valor por 255 para obtener números entre 0 y 1
    const [R, G, B] = pairs.map((pair) => parseInt(pair, 16) / 255);

    // 4. obtén el valor de K para luego computar los valores de C, M y Y
    // siguiendo esta formula:
    const _K = 1 - Math.max.call(null, R, G, B);
    // _K contiene el valor de K pero con posibles decimales

    // D será un divisor en la formula posterior que podría llegar a valer 0
    // lo computamos antes por seguridad para evitar división por 0 más adelante
    const D = 1 - _K;

    // si es 0, sabemos que los demás valores serán 0
    // este caso se puede dar si todos los valores RGB son 0, es decir, si el color es negro
    // 5. maneja esta excepción especial:
    if (!D) return { C: 0, M: 0, Y: 0, K: 100 };

    // función util para obtener el valor entero final redondeado:
    const round = (val) => Math.round(val * 100);

    // función util para calcular los valores de C, M y Y:
    const compute = (val) => (1 - val - _K) / D;

    // 6. calculamos y formateamos
    const C = round(compute(R));
    const M = round(compute(G));
    const Y = round(compute(B));
    const K = round(_K);

    return { C, M, Y, K };
  }

  // 7. captura el input
  const input = document.querySelector("input#color");

  // 8. agrega un handler al evento change del input
  input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    // 9. obtén el valor seleccionado
    const hex = e.target.value;
    // 10. convierte el color
    const cmyk = hexToCmyk(hex);

    console.log(cmyk);
  });
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="color" id="color" name="color" value="#e66465" />
  <label for="color">Selecciona un color</label>
</div>
```